# Ruby on Rails 4 - friendly_id with nested routed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id, nested-resources

I have a nested rout for toys and then toys will have reviews. The toys works fine with friendly_id but going to website.com/toys/toy-name/reviews/new brings up

`Couldn't find Toy without an ID`

My routes file looks like this

```
 resources :toys do
   resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
 end
```

The reviews controller has a set_toy method that is called before_action and is where the error is occurring. The method looks like

```
 def set_toy
  @toy = Toy.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

The toys controller has a similar method called toy_params that has exactly the same contents.

I can't see why the reviews controller cannot find the toy ID as I have passed it in with friendly.find.

Thank you

Comment: What's the stacktrace for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need

```
 def set_toy
   @toy = Toy.friendly.find(params[:toy_id])
 end
```

in your reviews controller.